Version 4 of flutter_braintree crashes the app on Android when using Paypal
When updating flutter_braintree from version 3.0.0 to version 4.0.0, the app crashes when using it in Android for Paypal.
I added the new configuration to the AndroidManifest:
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.DropInActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
                <data android:scheme="com.xxxxxx.android.braintree" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
</activity> 
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.ThreeDSecureActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:exported="true"> </activity>

and it crashes the same.
My applicationId is compliant, this is not the problem.
flutter_braintree package
The error in console is:
error PlatformException(error, Unable to find explicit activity class {com.xxxxxx.android/com.example.flutter_braintree.FlutterBraintreeCustom}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared \<intent-filter\>?, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.xxxxxx.android/com.example.flutter_braintree.FlutterBraintreeCustom}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared \<intent-filter\>?*
*at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2217)*
*at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1859)*
*at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5622)*
*at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.kt:704)*
*at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5575)*
*at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.kt:683)*
*at com.example.flutter_braintree.FlutterBraintreePlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterBraintreePlugin.java:111)*
*at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)*
*at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)*
*at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)*
*at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)

If I add the following activity in AndroidManifest, the app does not crash, it opens that blank window and goes to the Paypal website, but does not return to the app, in addition to showing an empty window between the app and PayPal.
<activity android:name="com.example.flutter_braintree.FlutterBraintreeCustom" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:exported="true">
        </activity>

